# Krakenjs How to route all requests except some api calls to index.html?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, single-page-application, kraken.js

How do I route all requests to index.html except some api calls and maybe some pages. since kraken way of routing is based on controller's directory, so if i do

```
// /controller/index.js
app.get('*', function(){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
```

kraken would route all my requests to index.html including the api calls in /controller/api directory. so how can i make kraken to route some requests like /api to the /controller/api/index.js and the rest to /public/templates/index.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd put it as middleware after the router (use priority to make sure it ends up in the right place)

```
module.exports = function setupJustServeTheAppEverywhere() {
   return function (req, res, next) {
      res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
   }
};
```

And have the config load that.

Comment: i works but how do i know if there is "file not found" or "internal server error" exceptions if i redirect all the routes to index.html?

Comment: That is indeed the problem with that approach and offloading all rendering to the client. I much prefer rendering server-side to initialize, which means your whole routing setup is actually explicit, rather than fallback-based like this.

Comment: Errors will still show up, but file not found will be hidden. This app will never 404 if you do this.